# How to send data in jquery with POST method?

Tags: php, jquery

I need to have this function: an user login using Facebook login. As soon as the user's connected, some Facebook data needs to be sent using the POST method, so another page (setSes.php) can handle the data.

I've created the code below, (added an extra alert to see if the data is loaded as it should, which works just fine), but somehow the page setSes.php is not getting called.

```
function login() {
       FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Connected';

            FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,link,gender,locale,picture.width(9999).height(9999)'}, function(response) {
                var id=response.id;
                var firstName=response.first_name;
                var lastName=response.last_name;
                var picture=response.picture.data.url;
                alert("Selected ID= "+id);

                $.ajax({
                url:"/setSes.php ",
                method:"POST",

                data:{
                  UID: "id",
                  firstName: "firstName",
                  lastName: "lastName",
                  picture: "picture"
                }
              });
            });
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Not connected';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Not able to login';
        }
       }, {scope: 'email'});
   }
```

**setSes.php**

```
<? 
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, oauth_uid, picture
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST["firstName"], $_POST["lastName"], $_POST["UID"], $_POST["picture"]);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();

    echo "I ran";

?>
```

Comment: `type="post"` will do the trick. remove your `method`

Comment: nope, unfortunately didn't work :(

Comment: then go with $.post https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: `type` is `an alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0`.

Comment: Open up the network tab on your browser and click the button. You should be able to see both the request to the server for /setSes.php and a response object from the server as to whether or not it was successful. Its unlikely you wont get a response as it seems to be getting into the method so let me know what response you get i.e. 200, 404, 500 etc.

Comment: is `url:"/setSes.php "` correct? is that the right URL? if you write it in your navigator, it calls your page PHP?

Comment: @MasterYoda It doesn't show the setSes.php at all. Only the request to facebook, this has a status 200

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL yeah page is right. I can write it in my navigator, no problems then

Comment: does `setSes.php` return anything? add an `echo "I ran";` at the end.

Comment: Is that the whole content of setSes.php?

Comment: @A.Iglesias yeah, except for a session_start that's all

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL I've added the echo "I ran" but that's not showing me anything. But I'm not sure if that's even an error, as the page is requested over the script, not actually loaded on the screen...

Comment: Please, paste the exact content of `setSes.php` (edit the question)

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but is just to be sure. You're sure you have the jQuery loaded and is working, right (you use it for other things in your code and is working)? Do you have any console error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ajax call you're passing strings, not the variables obtained. For your comments, the `setSes.php`file is in the same directory, so try this...

```
var id = response.id,
    fName = response.first_name,
    lName = response.last_name,
    pic = response.picture.data.url;

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "setSes.php",
    data: { UID: id, firstName: fName, lastName: lName, picture: pic },
    success: function(response) {
        alert('SUCCESS: ' + response);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('ERROR');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `setSes.php` in the same directory as the file with the jQuery code?

Comment: Yes it is in the same dir.

Comment: It gave an error on the $.ajax. Fixed it, now it's working!

Comment: Good to hear! What was the error (if you don't mind)?

Comment: I copied your code, just copy/paste. But didn't notice that a `,` was missing after the data.

Comment: Still, you've helped me a lot! Thanks for your answer and your effort